# Modify Subkey in Registry using C#

Tags: c#, registry

I need to change the subkey in registry.

I googled a lot and din't found any way to change the subkey.

Is Microsoft supporting this feature?

I am able to change the key/value pair but not subkey using  this

```
Registry.SetValue(keypath, subkey, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
```

Comment: Look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170886/edit-registry-keys

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to change the "default value" use a blank string as the value name when setting it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `RegistryKey.CreateSubKey` method.

Example (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx.aspx):

```
 RegistryKey test9999 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Test9999");
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to change on the subkey? If it's the name, this is read only and can not be changed.
Regedit can rename keys by creating a new one and individually copying each sub key and value to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void WriteRegistry(RegistryKey parentKey, String subKey, String valueName, Object value)
{
        RegistryKey key;
    try
    {
        key = parentKey.OpenSubKey(subKey, true);
        if(key == null) //If the key doesn't exist.
                {
           key = parentKey.CreateSubKey(subKey);
                }

        //Set the value.
        key.SetValue(valueName, value);

        Console.WriteLine("Value:{0} for {1} is successfully written.", value, valueName);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occurs in WriteRegistry" + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will create a subkey. while i already have a subkey and now need to change the name/value of the subkey.

Comment: Actually if you look at the code it only creates a subkey if one doesn't exist already, hence the check on whether OpenSubKey returns a null value.