# Edit Registry Keys

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, registry, registrykey

i need to edit those registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network
```

to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal-
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network-
```

I tried with

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal", true);
```

but then there is not rename,copy method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Copy and Rename Registry Keys](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16343/Copy-and-Rename-Registry-Keys) project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

// RenameRegistryKey © Copyright 2006 Active Computing
namespace RenameRegistryKey
{
    public class RegistryUtilities
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Renames a subkey of the passed in registry key since 
        /// the Framework totally forgot to include such a handy feature.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="regKey">The RegistryKey that contains the subkey 
        /// you want to rename (must be writeable)</param>
        /// <param name="subKeyName">The name of the subkey that you want to rename
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="newSubKeyName">The new name of the RegistryKey</param>
        /// <returns>True if succeeds</returns>
        public bool RenameSubKey(RegistryKey parentKey, 
            string subKeyName, string newSubKeyName)
        {
            CopyKey(parentKey, subKeyName, newSubKeyName);
            parentKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(subKeyName);
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Copy a registry key.  The parentKey must be writeable.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parentKey"></param>
        /// <param name="keyNameToCopy"></param>
        /// <param name="newKeyName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool CopyKey(RegistryKey parentKey, 
            string keyNameToCopy, string newKeyName)
        {
            //Create new key
            RegistryKey destinationKey = parentKey.CreateSubKey(newKeyName);

            //Open the sourceKey we are copying from
            RegistryKey sourceKey = parentKey.OpenSubKey(keyNameToCopy);

            RecurseCopyKey(sourceKey, destinationKey);

            return true;
        }

        private void RecurseCopyKey(RegistryKey sourceKey, RegistryKey destinationKey)
        {
            //copy all the values
            foreach (string valueName in sourceKey.GetValueNames())
            {        
                object objValue = sourceKey.GetValue(valueName);
                RegistryValueKind valKind = sourceKey.GetValueKind(valueName);
                destinationKey.SetValue(valueName, objValue, valKind);
            }

            //For Each subKey 
            //Create a new subKey in destinationKey 
            //Call myself 
            foreach (string sourceSubKeyName in sourceKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                RegistryKey sourceSubKey = sourceKey.OpenSubKey(sourceSubKeyName);
                RegistryKey destSubKey = destinationKey.CreateSubKey(sourceSubKeyName);
                RecurseCopyKey(sourceSubKey, destSubKey);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this exception don't cause by a permission issue? This code works on my machine.

Comment: Yeah it's a premission issue but i tried by running it as administrator, still the same

Comment: You can try there http://superuser.com/questions/181881/how-do-you-change-permissions-on-a-registry-key-windows-7 and http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/13811.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310426/en-us

Comment: Excellent helper class. Dropped it in and it Just Worked. I took the liberty of making my copy of the class and its methods static since they have no state, so the caller can just call `RegistryUtilities.RenameSubKey()` instead of needing to create a `RegistryUtilities` object.

Comment: I think you might need to use `RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames` on `GetValue` if the kind is REG_EXPAND_SZ.